# Two topics in Literature Review?

Tags: thesis

Im currently in the middle of writing my masters thesis and was hoping I could receive some guidance with regard to my literature review. 
I currently have discussed two topics in my literature review; 'populism' and 'nationalism' and was wondering if this is okay, or is a literature review meant to focus on one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on how narrow you want, how closely related your topics are, and what the rules and expectations are for a masters thesis at your school. This is probably a question better suited for professors in your department who have a better idea what your school's specific norms are your institution.

Comment: The question _if this is okay_ is for your advisor. Please ask them.